# Dependency bundle (jar-files/sources/API docs) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, netbeans, build

I'm developing various in-house extensions for JIRA, the issue tracker we use.  So far I worked with Netbeans and everything worked like a charm.  However, now I need to switch to Eclipse and I'm having struggle setting up the environment for this development project.

First a clarification why I'm using the approach I'm describing here:  building JIRA (in an IDE) is not easily done and I'm absolutely not interested in wasting my time to figure out how to do it.  Besides, I don't need to build it, I just want to develop extensions and be able to use the IDE's auto-completion and help support (API docs).  Atlassian (the company that develops JIRA) provides a "development" package, but it's just a sorry excuse rather than a real solution.

What I did with Netbeans was to create a library bundle with all relevant jar-files, the Java source files and the API documentation.  This way I could use auto-completion, "jump to" the source and the API docs would pop-up when needed.

It seems Eclipse doesn't offer such a functionality, at least I couldn't figure out how to add the sources and the API docs to a "User Library" (which I'd then add as a dependency to my project just as with Netbeans).

My next approach was to create a separate project that holds all the stuff and mark that project as a dependency of my project.  This works, but it leaves me with another issue: now I get 37k errors reported (all within the "dependency project").  As said, correctly setting up building for this dependency is a major struggle and *not my original goal*, therefore I'd happily ignore these errors.  Automatic building is turned off and changing the "Errors/Warnings" settings under "Java Compiler" for the project didn't change a thing, so I'm kind of lost now.

Okay, let me try to phrase this as questions:

1. Maybe I just didn't find it: Is there a way to create a dependency bundle (call it whatever you want) in Eclipse that -- besides just carrying jar-files -- gives me the ability to use the API docs and "jump to" the declaration in the sources?
2. If not, what's the common practice to do in such a situation?
3. If the "dependency project" solution is the way to go, how can I completely disable compiler errors for that project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this for illustration with images

[Add the source code for jar](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarsource)

[Add the Javadoc for a jar](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarjavadoc)

Or just right-click on the jar file in the Package Explorer view. Select "Properties" then set the according paths in the "Java Source Attachment" and the "Javadoc Location" field.

Answer (score 1):

When you create user libs via window->preferences->java-build path->user libraries you can specify which jar you need, sources (in archive or folder) && javadoc (from internet, or local, or from archive). Then you can use this lib in your project via context menu on project->Build path->add library->user library-> choose your lib.

Here you acn pick up more info [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm)

Comment: The step I missed was to "open" the JAR resources by clicking on the plus... From there on everything's clear.